# PHP - Mysql date conversion

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm noticing some strange results with date conversions between MYSQL and PHP.
Please see the following

PHP: strtotime(25-Mar-2012) returns 1332626400
Mysql: FROM_UNIXTIME(1332626400) returns 2012-03-25 00:00:00
That results are as expected.

**The Problem:**

Php: strtotime(26-Mar-2012) returns 1332709200
Mysql: FROM_UNIXTIME(1332709200) returns 2012-03-25 23:00:00

I expect FROM_UNIXTIME to return "2012-03-26" i.e. (March 26 instead of March 25)

Ignoring the time as follows doesn't help either:
FROM_UNIXTIME(1332709200,'%Y-%m-%d') returns 2012-03-25

Any idea what's happening here?

Comment: this might have something to do with Daylight Saving time - as it changes on that day ....

Comment: `strtotime()` is timezone aware. What does http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php return?

Comment: Daylights saving is probably the problem. Best you store dates/times as UTC then covert for the particular individual depending on their time zone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried following query on mysql
    SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME( 1332709200 ) AS time;
And it returned '2012-03-26 02:30:00'.
So it seems something to do with daylight saving or timezone on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the timezones in PHP and your MySQL server differ. The difference in your result is exactly 1 hour and your data source is in seconds. That can't be a coincident. Seems like UTC +1 or UTC -1

Answer (score 0):

Check `date.timezone` variable in your PHP.ini. In my case (Europe/Budapest) it throws the correct value:

```
$ php -r "echo strtotime('26-Mar-2012');"
1332712800
```